# Random <div> movement

Tags: html, css

I have two div elements that keeps loading further down the page than it is supposed to, the one containing the "sign up" section and the search bar. Sometimes when I load the page it will do this and sometimes it won't, I can't figure out what is causing it. Also I cannot figure out how to make one of my tr (one;s with class "descr") shorter than the others in the table, I tried setting the height of the tr and the td's inside it and neither worked. I would greatly appreciate any insight!

link to Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/n29LLonn/

```css
    * {


      margin: 0px;


      padding: 0px;


    }


    #header {


      /*border: 1px dotted;*/


      width: 900px;


      height: 135px;


      margin-left: auto;


      margin-right: auto;


    }


    #header_top {


      border: 1px dotted;


      height: 50%;


      position: relative;


    }


    #header_bottom {


      border: 1px dotted;


      height: 50%;


      position: relative;


    }


    .inline {


      /*border: 1px dotted;*/


      display: inline-block;


      height: 100%;


    }


    .margin {


      margin-left: 15px;


    }


    .right {


      float: right;


    }


    #body {


      /*border: 1px dotted;*/


      width: 900px;


      height: 1500px;


      margin-left: auto;


      margin-right: auto;


    }


    #big_pic {


      /*border: 1px dotted;*/


      width: 900px;


      height: 632px;


    }


    #big_shoe {


      width: 900px;


      height: 632px;


    }


    #shoe_table {


      /*border: 1px dotted;*/


      width: 100%;


      height: 868px;


    }


    #shoe_table table {


      margin-top: 10px;


      width: 100%


    }


    #shoe_table table td {


      /*border: 1px dotted;*/


      height: 161px;


      width: 221px;


    }


    .menu_shoe {


      width: 221px;


      height: 161px;


    }


    .descr {


      height: 20px !important;


    }


    #footer {


      /*border: 1px dotted;
    width: 900px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;*/


    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="txt/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">
    <div id="header_top">
      <div class="inline">
        <h1>Sample Logo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="inline margin">
        <p><a href="">Sell</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="inline margin">
        <p><a href="">Find us on Facebook and Twitter</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="inline margin right">
        <p><a href="">Sign in</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="header_bottom">
      <div class="inline">
        <p><a href="">Home</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="inline margin">
        <p><a href="">Release Calender</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="inline margin">
        <p><a href="">Jordans</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="inline margin">
        <p><a href="">Shopping Cart</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="inline margin right">
        <form>
          <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="body">
    <div id="big_pic">
      <img src="images/shoe.jpg" id="big_shoe" alt="Air Jordan 1 Retro High OG 'UNC'">
    </div>
    <div id="shoe_table">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="Air Jordan 1 retro high og 'unc'">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe2.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 1 RETRO OG 'CYBER MONDAY'">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe3.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 2 RETR0">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe4.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 2 RETRO DON C">
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="descr">
          <td>
            <p>Air Jordan 1 retro high og "unc" $225</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 1 RETRO OG "CYBER MONDAY" $225</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 2 RETR0 $250</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 2 RETRO DON C "DON C" $1,200</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe5.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 3 RETRO 'INFRARED 2'">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe6.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 3 RETRO DB 'DOERNBECHER'">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe7.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 4 RETRO LS 'LEGEND BLUE'">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe8.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 4 RETRO 'COOL GREY'">
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="descr">
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 3 RETRO "INFRARED 23" $325</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 3 RETRO DB "DOERNBECHER" $850</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 4 RETRO LS "LEGEND BLUE" $300</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 4 RETRO "COOL GREY" $550</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe9.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 5 RETRO '2015 RELEASE'">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe10.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 5 RETRO SUPREME 'SUPREME'">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe11.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 6 RETRO LOW 'CHROME'">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe12.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 6 RINGS PREMIER 'MOTOR SPORT'">
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="descr">
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 5 RETRO "2015 RELEASE" $250</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 5 RETRO SUPREME "SUPREME" $550</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 6 RETRO LOW "CHROME" $250</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 6 RINGS PREMIER "MOTOR SPORT" $350</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe13.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 7 RETRO 'BORDEAUX 2015'">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe14.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 7 RETRO (GS) 'OLYMPIC 2012 RELEASE'">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe15.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 8 RETRO 'AQUA 2015'">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe16.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 8 RETRO DB 'DOERNBECHER'">
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="descr">
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 7 RETRO "BORDEAUX 2015" $300</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 7 RETRO (GS) "OLYMPIC 2012 RELEASE" $500</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 8 RETRO "AQUA 2015" $275</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 8 RETRO DB "DOERNBECHER" $1,000</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe17.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 9 RETRO BG (GS) 'ANTHRACITE'">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe18.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 9 RETRO PREMIO 'BIN23'">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe19.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 10 RETRO 'DOUBLE NICKEL'">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="">
              <img src="images/shoe20.jpg" class="menu_shoe" alt="AIR JORDAN 10 RETRO DB 'DOERNBECHER'">
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="descr">
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 9 RETRO BG (GS) "ANTHRACITE" $200</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 9 RETRO PREMIO "BIN23" $2,000</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 10 RETRO "DOUBLE NICKEL" $240</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>AIR JORDAN 10 RETRO DB "DOERNBECHER" $500</p>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--<div id="footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>-->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried to replicate this but it's a little tough without the images. Are you able to give us a test page or something so we can see exactly what you mean?

Comment: Give us a fiddle please.

Comment: Sorry, link to fiddle added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to your table so that you have complete control of cell width and height:

```
table-layout: fixed;
border-spacing: .5em .75em;
```

I don't see the search bar or any other element jump randomly upon reload. It might be the service you are hosting your site on. Do you have ads or using Word-Press, or a CMS?

Here's a demo, if there's a significant difference, it's because I created it before you had your demo posted. There were several mistakes like CJ Nimes mentioned that I corrected, and I changed most of the divs into a more suitable element. I also made it semi-responsive as well.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ziub2bbuVHHQ63sDJVnZ?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! That definitely helped with my table issue, the header is still being bothersome , I don't have any ads and I'm not using wordpress or a CMS, so I'm not sure...hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, the "link" tag isn't closed:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="txt/css" href="style.css"
```

Here, `</a>` is missing:

```
<div class="inline"><p><a href="">Home</p></div>
```

Here, `</p></a>` should be `</a></p>`:

```
    <div class="inline margin"><p><a href="">Jordans</p></a></div>
    <div class="inline margin"><p><a href="">Shopping Cart</p></a></div>
```

And `</body></html>` is missing too.

Comment: The </body> and the </html> were accidentally left out when I copy pasted my code to this post, but I did fix the mistakes you pointed out and it is still randomly shifting the sign up and search bar down